# Where can I find synchronous machine datasheet?

Tags: power, power-engineering, power-grid

In the laboratory where I work, we have developed our own MATLAB library for simulating transient response of power systems, and I am currently working on some simulations of IEEE 9 bus system.

I was looking for power flow, transmission line and machinery data for accurate simulating the system behavior, but I could not find the machinery data related to this power grid. For example, I need the reactances, the damping factor, the inertia coefficient and other parameters. Does anyone know where can I find this kind of information?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Something as this ? https://www.pscad.com/knowledge-base/download/ieee_9_bus_technical_note.pdf

Comment: Sorry, but this file does not contain the machinery data I am looking for (synchronous machine reactances, damping factor and others). Therefore, I accepted @pdb5627 answer. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the original test case had dynamic model information developed with it, but there is a "modified" version of the IEEE 9-bus model that includes dynamic machine models at https://www.kios.ucy.ac.cy/testsystems/index.php/ieee-9-bus-modified-test-system/.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you very much for your help!